# Adjusting the sampling probability during sampling

Tags: survey-sampling, survey-weights, design-based-inference

Let $n$ individuals in a [statistical population](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Statistical_population) be identified by $p.id \in \{1, 2, ..., n\}$ where the order is randomised. Assume, for simplicity, that all individuals are included in the [sampling frame](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sampling_frame) and could, in principal, be sampled. Also for simplicity, assume there is no complex survey design (no [clustering](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cluster_sampling) or [stratification](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stratified_sampling)) but merely a [simple random sample](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simple_random_sample).

The researcher initially thinks that $10\%$ of the invited individuals will [respond](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Response_rate_(survey)) to the survey and hopes to get around $100$ respondents. So she invites the first $1000$ individuals ($p.id \in \{1, ..., 1000\}$) from the sampling frame to participate.

After two weeks, only $5\%$ of the invited participants has responded. So the researcher invites the next set of $1000$ individuals ($p.id \in \{1001, ..., 2000\}$) to participate.

Given the random order of the individuals in the sampling frame, it can be argued that this is a probability sample. However, the decision to continue sampling after a low response rate sounds very similar to [quota sampling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quota_sampling), which is a type of [non-probability sampling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nonprobability_sampling).

- Is the described procedure probability sampling?
- How does the answer depend on whether there is non-response bias or not?
- How does the answer depend on whether there is clustering or stratification?
- What is the [sampling probability](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sampling_probability) of $p.id \in \{1, ..., 1000\}$?
- What is the sampling probability of $p.id \in \{1001, ..., 2000\}$?
- What are the problems with quota sampling which make it non-probability based?
- Are there any problems with the procedure described above?